# Design MYSQL Database Table for shopping card

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

First time i design database table i really need a help to design good database table.

i am totally confused to design product attribute table but i did please checked that design and help me to improve database structure.

> product_categories

```
    category_id
    parent_category_id
    category_title
    category_slug
    category_description
    category_image
    include_in_menu
    display_mode
    display_mode_content
    category_status
```

> attribute

```
    attribute_id
    category_id
    attribute_title
    attribute_slug
    attribute_type
    attribute_table
    attribute_inputtype
    attribute_label
    is_required
    is_unique
    attribute_default_value
```

> attribute_order

```
    order_id
    attribute_id
    sort_order
```

> attribute_value

```
    attribute_value_id
    attribute_id
    value
```

> product

```
    product_id
    product_categories_id
    product_sku
    product_title
    product_slug
    product_description
    product_short_description
    product_brand_id
    product_warranty
    product_images
    product_price
    product_selling_price
    product_qty
    product_height
    product_weight
    product_length
    product_status
```

> product_attribute

```
    attribute_id
    product_id
    attribute_value
```

please also give a suggestion if i need to change my table or field name. please correct me if i did any mistake in database design.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: This question is more suitable for either code review or dba sites.

Comment: Don't include an `AUTO_INCRMENT` `PRIMARY KEY` when you have a 'natural' PK that would work.

Comment: key-value is a painful schema design.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have many tables, for example:

```
Products:
    ID
    Name
    Description
    Etc...

Categories:
    ID
    Name

ProductCategories:
    ProductID
    CategoryID

Types:
    ID
    Name

ProductTypes:
    ProductID
    TypeID
```

You'll have many tables, for example:

Products:
    ID
    Name
    Description
    Etc...

Categories:
    ID
    Name

ProductCategories:
    ProductID
    CategoryID

Types:
    ID
    Name

ProductTypes:
    ProductID
    TypeID

This enables you to have products in multiple categories and of multiple types...

Added further examples as per the comment below. For sizes you have a Sizes table, and a mapping table to map products to sizes...

```
Sizes:
    ID
    Name

ProductSizes:
    ProductID
    SizeID
```

If you also need to consider colours, and need to make a choice whether you will store sizes that have a colour, or colours that have a size...

```
Colours:
    ID
    Name

ProductColours
    ProductID
    ColourID
```

Or, if you need colours and sizes, or any further complexity, i would abstract it right out and use a ProductAttributes way of doing it, maybe out of the scope of this question as the answer would be quite lengthy indeed.

But in the same style as above, you could have a table like so:

```
ProductSizesColours:
    ProductID
    SizeID
    ColourID
```